# Quarkus ApiResponse is 200 OK but the body of the response is incomplete

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, chunked

I'm working in a project that uses Quarkus and at one endpoint we are returning a JSON response that is bigger than 8K. Not all the responses bigger than 8K are failing but this one in particular is failing.

To make matters worse, the response's status code is 200 OK, although the body is incomplete.

If we change in the application.yml the vertx buffer size to a size bigger than our response, it works. It only stops working when the response code is chunked.

Any one has any tips on what else could be wrong? Any idea on how can I debug this issue? It seems to be a problem with Vertx.

In postman and curl the response is ok. It doesn't seem to be a problem on the client side. I suspect it is on quarkus' vertx but I can't find a good way to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for the answer to this...

We were/are using version 2.6.1.Final. Upgrading to version 2.7.5.Final has fixed the issue.

I know there are newer versions but they have some breaking changes.